# invert the direction of a particles in matlab

Tags: matlab, particles, direction

i have a problem with an algorithm, i have a space with x,y coordinates and a low and upper bound. I have also some particles within this space free to move.
I want that any particle remains into my space and if one of those are moving out the bounders i need to change its direction. If there is no way to bring back the particle i can create a particle in a randomic point within my space.
I was thinking with a for loop that check each particles and when one moves out to bring it back to the opposit direction, but i don' t know how to write it.

Comment: you should add some example input and desired output

Comment: can you give a small sample of your data and the expected result you want from this data?

Comment: i have in input the position and the velocity vector of a particle, if this vector goes out the upper bound or the lower bound i need to reverse the direction of the vector, so in this way i have my particle within the space.

Comment: one example i tried is:
for i = 0 : number_particles ;
   if ( velocity(i, 7:11) > upperBound || lowerBound       % i have 5  dimensions so i need 5 columns for the velocity, after that i would  write somthing for the condition to turn back the vector of velocity

Comment: In order to give more information, please edit the question, do not use comments for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without your information, I am going to guess how I'd do it:

```
part_location=rand(10,2); % 10 particles
part_direction=rand(10,2); % non-normalized direction so it has also speed
boundaries=[0,0;1 1]; % square boundary from 0 to 1; not going to use it so I dont write your whole code.


for ii=1:nsteps_simulation
    % update particle position using direction
    % do it
    part_location= ... ?
    % check if particles are inside the boundary

    inside=sum(part_location>0 && part_location<1,2)==2;

    outside=~inside;

    % now you know which particles are inside and wich outside.
    % Inverting the direction should be easy

    part_direction=...?

end
```

Apologise if the code is not complete, but nobody is going to write it for you! 
However, I hope that I have given you a clear structure of how you should design an algorithm for this. Of course, depending on your data/application you'd need to modify the structure a bit, but this is probably the most you'll get without more information or show us what you tried!

Comment: Thank you, of course i will wtite by myself but you explained me my problems!

Comment: @Andy If you found it useful and you think this is the answer you were looking for, accept the asnwer for the sake of the community!

Comment: why did you write ==2??           sum(part_location>0 && part_location<1,2)==2;

Comment: It makes sure that the point is inside the boundary. If only one is inside  (`sum(p,2)==1`) then the other coordinate is out.

Comment: @AnderBiguri, amazing powers of divination! :-)

Comment: I think I would not only revert the direction, but mirror the particle outside of the box into the box. That would be the cleanest implementation of a reflection in discrete time.